Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render (NextJS)
On visiting website localhost:3000/ I am navigating user to /home or /admin/dashboard based on roles saved in local storage.
When admin is logged in (role=admin in local storage) and I open new tab (as localhost:3000/) it gives me a splash screen of this:

This error is in console for a sec
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render (NextJS)

Then after this it shows the /home for 2 sec. Then it navigates to /admin/dashboard
I want it to be smooth (direct navigation to /admin/dashboard)
I saw multiple posts on stackoverflow but cant get through with my problem
AuthGuard.jsx
"use client";
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';

const AuthGuard = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const role = localStorage.getItem('role');
    const token = localStorage.getItem('custom-auth-token');

    if (token) {
      if (role === 'buyer') {
        router.push('/home');
      } else if (role === 'seller') {
        router.push('/admin/dashboard');
      }
    } else {
      // If no token is present, redirect to /home
      router.push('/home');
    }
  }, [router]);

  return <>{children}</>;
};

export default AuthGuard;


layout.jsx
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { ReduxProvider } from "@/redux/provider/redux-provider";
import AuthGuard from "@/components/auth/auth-guard";


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Car Lease",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthGuard>
          <ReduxProvider>{children}</ReduxProvider>
        </AuthGuard>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


page.jsx
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export default function Page() {
  redirect('/home');
}


I want the navigation to be smooth (direct navigation to /admin/dashboard) I saw multiple posts on stackoverflow but cant get through with my problem
